# How to plot a list of cards with images and text in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview, android-image, card

How to print list of cards with images and text paragraphs as per the card index in flutter? That means suppose I have a Notification page and I have to show the upcoming notifications in a list of cards format. If I have birthday notification then I have to show the birthday photo along with the birthday text for the user.
If I have a reminder then I have to show the reminder text with a calendar photo in a card, like that

Comment: This article might help you https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb

Answer (score 0):

This is a class for list as you want,just change the icons acording to your logic

```
class NotificationListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: kTextColor),
          title: Text(
            'Notifications',
            style:
            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins-regular', color: kTextColor),
          ),
          backgroundColor: kPrimaryLightColor,
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("this is title"),
              subtitle: Text("this is subtitle"),
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.account_box)),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("this is title"),
              subtitle: Text("this is subtitle"),
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.account_box)),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("this is title"),
              subtitle: Text("this is subtitle"),
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.account_box)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```